# Visual Studio 16.8 breaks .NET Framework 4.8 WPF build

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've now updated to Visual Studio 16.8, and with that, my existing (large) solution fails to build any WPF projects. Error messages such as the following everywhere:

```
10>C:\...\src\UserInterface\DataWriterMonitor\App.xaml.cs(5,25,5,28): error CS1558: "App" hat keine passende statische Main-Methode.
10>C:\...\UserInterface\DataWriterMonitor\App.xaml.cs(9,4,9,23): error CS0103: Der Name "InitializeComponent" ist im aktuellen Kontext nicht vorhanden.
```

Obviously, it's failing to pre-process the xaml files. When I change the csproj header of the offending project from `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">` I get:

```
10>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(240,9): error MC1000: Unbekannter Buildfehler, "Could not find assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Either explicitly load this assembly using a method such as LoadFromAssemblyPath() or use a MetadataAssemblyResolver that returns a valid assembly."
```

This even happens if I remove all direct references from the project.

Different other approaches (including setting the sdk to 4.8 in global.json) generated different error messages, but didn't work either.

**How can I make that the build does not use the 5.0 SDK?** I need it installed for other projects, but here I just want my solution to build as before with .NET Framework 4.8.

<strike>Note: I've tried the sample .NET 4.8 WPF app. This one builds, but it uses the old project file format. If I change it to the new format, I get similar problems.</strike>  After some fiddling, that now works, possibly because this otherwise empty project has no references at all.

Comment: You can set the SDK version in a [`global.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x)

Comment: @canton: I've tried that. What would need to go there? My global.json reads: `{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "4.8"
  }
}`

Comment: What version of the SDK were you using previously? You were targetting .NET Framework 4.8 sure, but that's not the SDK version you were using to do the build. The SDKs are listed [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) under ".NET Core"

Comment: Your project file is invalid. A WPF project targeting .NET Framework cannot use the SDK style project. Even if it works for you ever, Microsoft can easily break that (as that’s not a supported scenario) IMHO.

Comment: @LexLi: Apparently it can. We've used SDK style projects since a long time. And just now I managed to build the sample WPFApp project with an SDK style project.

Comment: @LexLi It can. Create a new .NET Core WPF app (with the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK), then change the TargetFramework to net472, etc, and it's fine. It can even multi-target Core and Framework (although I needed to use MSBuild.SDK.Extras for that)

Comment: @canton7 Good question, I don't know what was used before. I assume the latest pre-5.0 version.

Comment: "It can" is rather weak a claim, as .NET 5 introduced fundamental changes in how WPF projects are compiled. The lucky old approach can fail and someone might fix that later. Use the VS menu item to report this to Microsoft.

Comment: @PMF try `"3.1.404"` then? Also see what SDKs you have installed with `dotnet --info`

Comment: @canton7: Set it to 3.1.101 now (since I have that one installed). The change works, but the error still persists: `10>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(225,9): error MC1000: Unbekannter Buildfehler, "Could not find assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Either explicitly load this assembly using a method such as LoadFromAssemblyPath() or use a MetadataAssemblyResolver that returns a valid assembly."`

Comment: I don't think there's much more we can suggest without a repro unfortunately. If you're targetting Framework from an SDK-style project do look into using MSBuild.SDK.Extras, it fixes a lot of the problems which otherwise pop up

Answer (score 0):

I apparently did too many things at once. Using a `global.json` with

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.101"
  }
}
```

and no other changes (especially no change to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`) fixed the build.

Comment: Wait, you said you changed it *to* `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`. Did you actually change it *from* the value?

Comment: I first had changed it _to_ that value, but I had to undo this to make the global.json change work as expected (or I would still get the System.Web assembly not found error)

Answer (score 0):

I removed `<usewpf>true</usewpf>` from my projects

Comment: That works only if the projects don't actually use WPF. Mine do.